# Meteor - How to use {{each}} to display multiple arrays from mongoDB in a table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, html-table, each

I have a collection named "pIds" in mongoDB and with multiple arrays:

```
{
    "_id" : "Coms>f41a3480af751a7a",
    "pIds" : [ 
        "pid_833d82c2f32b7dc0", 
        "pid_833d82c2f32b7dc0", 
        "pid_833d82c2f32b7dc0", 
    ],
    "dudes" : [ 
        "AB", 
        "AC",
        "BC" 
    ],
    "ho" : [ 
        "Coms>f41a3480af751a7a", 
        "Coms>f41a3480af751a7a", 
        "Coms>f41a3480af751a7a"
    ],
    "ps" : [ 
        "vf", 
        "ou", 
        "rwf"
    ],

}
```

Now I want to render these elements dynamic into a HTML table so that the table changes the same way the data in the collection changes. So the table should automatically add new elements, when new elements are written into the collection "pIds". I thought about using {{each}}.

JS-Helper:

```
Template.home.helpers({ 
  'pIdsRendering': function() {
   if (Meteor.userId()) {
  var pId = pIds.find({'_id': Session.get('pIdshome')}).fetch();

    return pId;
  }
},
});
```

HTML:

```
                        <tbody>

{{#each pIdsRendering}}

        {{#each pIds}}

                            <tr><td>{{this}}</td></tr>
            {{/each}}
{{/each}}

{{#each pIdsRendering}}

        {{#each dudes}}

                            <tr><td>{{this}}</td></tr>

         {{/each}}

  {{/each}}
            [...and so on...] 

                        </tbody>
```

Actually this works and new elements are added to the table, but I just can´t put the content into the right cells of the table. It puts the content all in one column like the data of the table would be written like this:

[image]

So, I think it is about "logical order", but I just can not get it done...In the end the table should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create for every array item new `<tr>` tag and this is the reason why every item is in a new row. I suggest you to change your collection schema a little bit. I would do it like below:

```
{
  "_id" : "Coms>f41a3480af751a7a",
  "data": [
    {
      "pid": "pid_833d82c2f32b7dc0",
      "dude": "AB",
      "ho": "Coms>f41a3480af751a7a",
      "ps": "vf"
    },
    {
      "pid": "pid_833d82c2f32b7dc0",
      "dude": "AC",
      "ho": "Coms>f41a3480af751a7a",
      "ps": "ou"
    }    
  ]
}
```

Then in your Blaze template you can show records much easier

```
{{ #each record }}
  {{ #each data }}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ pid }}</td>
      <td>{{ dude }}</td>
      <td>{{ ho }}</td>
      <td>{{ ps }}</td>
    </tr>
  {{ /each }}
{{ /each }}
```

Your actual schema can lead to unexpected errors. For example when `pIds` array will have more elements than `dudes`. It is more difficult to validate it. By using an object you can do it much more easily. Also, I guess that you want to bind pIds[index] element with dudes[index] element. In this case using arrays like you did isn't a correct way.

Comment: Your answer works perfect, many thanks! Changing the data schema to an object makes it much easier. Additionally, you are right, I want to bind the pIds[index] with dudes[index] and this is much easier by using an object.